# Crash report - EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)

Tags: crash, exc-bad-access

First time posting here and i'm new to this whole developer thing so please be nice!

I have submitted my app (a 3d game made in unity) and it has returned 3 crash reports, which all look pretty similar to me. I've put them through unity. I'll post one below (it was too long so i just posted the first bit) as they are so long, if you can help id be happy to post the other 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Incident Identifier: 938FFF53-56A2-4A1D-BF23-4E24567BA101
CrashReporter Key:   3286a932eadfb6a4501de9b1e0044450b3f54fb3
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Box [1376]
Path:                     /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/00E4561A-F30C-4C48-B2BD-355A71A4D971/Box.app/Box
Identifier:          Bob.Bob
Version:             1 (1)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-06-02 17:16:47.033 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-06-02 17:16:42.956 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000ff222c47
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x32123df0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x321a2cc3 pthread_kill + 59
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x320bf905 abort + 73
3   Box                             0x0182d908 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 312
4   Box                             0x0181d08c mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 256
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x3219e879 _sigtramp + 41
6   Box                             0x013e1f40 void ApplyMaterialPropertyBlockValuesMetal<SetValuesFunctorMetal>(MaterialPropertyBlock const&, GpuProgram*, GpuProgramParameters const*, ShaderType, SetValuesFunctorMetal&) (GpuProgramParamsApply.h:109)
7   Box                             0x013de9c4 GfxDeviceMetal::SetMaterialProperties(MaterialPropertyBlock const&) (GfxDeviceMetal.mm:513)
8   Box                             0x00ee48a0 ApplyBuiltinInstanceProperty::PerformFlushMaterialProperties() (ApplyBuiltinInstanceProperty.cpp:13)
9   Box                             0x00f39ebc Skybox::SetupSun(Camera const&, GfxDevice&) (Skybox.cpp:256)
10  Box                             0x00f3a218 Skybox::RenderSkybox(Unity::Material*, Camera const&) (Skybox.cpp:275)
11  Box                             0x00ef941c Camera::RenderSkybox() (Camera.cpp:780)
12  Box                             0x00ef3900 DoRenderLoop(RenderLoop&, RenderingPath, CullResults&, ShadowMapCache&, bool) (RenderLoopPrivate.cpp:416)
13  Box                             0x00efa604 Camera::DoRender(CullResults&, void (*)(Camera&, RenderLoop&, CullResults&), int) (Camera.cpp:1175)
14  Box                             0x00efad88 Camera::Render(CullResults&, ShaderLab::ShaderPassContext&, int) (Camera.cpp:1833)
15  Box                             0x00f2c438 RenderManager::RenderCameras(int) (RenderManager.cpp:111)
16  Box                             0x0104815c PlayerRender(bool) (Player.cpp:1490)
17  Box                             0x01048c0c PlayerLoop(bool, bool, IHookEvent*) (Player.cpp:1990)
18  Box                             0x00e13948 UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool) (LibEntryPoint.mm:209)
19  Box                             0x0008eb7c UnityRepaint (UnityAppController+Rendering.mm:199)
20  Box                             0x0009e5a4 -[UnityAppController(ViewHandling) showGameUI] (UnityAppController+ViewHandling.mm:160)
21  Box                             0x0009aeac -[UnityAppController startUnity:] (UnityAppController.mm:109)
22  Foundation                      0x24378369 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 465
23  CoreFoundation                  0x2360aedd __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 13
24  CoreFoundation                  0x2360aa57 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 647
25  CoreFoundation                  0x23608ca7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1415
26  CoreFoundation                  0x235551fd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 473
27  CoreFoundation                  0x2355500f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
28  GraphicsServices                0x2acf11fd GSEventRunModal + 133
29  UIKit                           0x26cf9a55 UIApplicationMain + 1437
30  Box                             0x000852b0 main (main.mm:40)
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x32059aad start + 1
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I think your question belongs to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . There you will get more attention on this issue as it's related to game development,

Comment: @kingAm Debugging is not specific to game development.